# I can't read in a file and write out to a file in Python

Tags: python

```
import sys 

def main():
    tclust_blue = open("ef_blue.xpk")
    tclust_original = open("tclust.txt","a")

    for line in tclust_blue.readlines():
        if "{}" in line: 
            tclust_original.write(line)
```

I'm having trouble reading in the file "ef_blue.xpk" which is in the same directory as my Python script as well as the same directory as the `tclust.txt` file. The error says:

> IO Error:[ErrNo 2] No such file or directory: 'ef_blue.xpk'

Also I don't know if my code is correct to begin with. I have a text file called tclust.txt, and I have lines in a file called ef_blue.xpk, and I want to grab values (not lines) from ef_blue.xpk and put them into tclust.txt.

The way I'm executing my file is through terminal by using a command 
`nfxsl readin.py`.

Comment: actually you should start the python console also from the same directory.

Comment: Note that a file doesn't have "values". It has bytes or characters. When you read them, it is up to you to interpret them into a meaningful value.

Comment: Please show how you execute your program. Also show an example input file.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice actually (and to be fully pedantic), a file has no characters either, all it "contains" are bytes, period ;)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Good point. Most languages, including Python, allow us to open a file in "text mode" so that translating bytes to characters is relatively painless. Translation to other types of values takes a little more work.

Comment: hi @Code-Apprentice thank you, I don't know exactly what you mean by how I execute my program. I am executing it through terminal. Also how can I show you what my input file is?

Comment: @Stack what does that mean?

Comment: Show the exact command you type from the terminal. Also, what directory are you in when you type the command? Is the input file binary or text?

Comment: I created an alias in my bash profile so that I can run it using the nfxsl command, and my file is text

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I called the main function and I still got the same error.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: What is `nfxsl`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice it's what I use to execute any python file. I have an alias in my bash profile which allows me to execute python scripts if i type the command nfxsl first

Comment: What is the alias? Why are you running python scripts with some program called `nfxsl` instead of running them with `python`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Okay so now I've changed it so that the file runs properly. But the code just doesn't come up with any output. Is there a way I can show you?

Comment: You should post a new question with the newest version of your code. Be sure to also show how you run the program and what the results are. Then explain how the actual results differ from what you want. See [ask] for more tips on asking a good question that will attract the answers you are looking for.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Okay, thanks very much for all your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script uses a relative path, and relative paths are not resolved against "where your script is" but against whatever the current working directory is when the code gets executed. If you don't want to depend on the current working directory (and very obviously you don't), you need to use absolute paths.

Here you have two options: pass the files (or directories...) path as command-line arguments, or use `sys.path` module's functions and the magic variable `__file__` to build an absolute path:

whereami.py:

```
import os
import sys

print("cwd : {}".format(os.getcwd()))
print("__file__ : {}".format(__file__))
print("abs file : {}".format(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

here = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
print("parent directory: {}".format(here))

sibling = os.path.join(here, "somefile.ext")
print("sibling with absolute path: {}".format(sibling))
```

Example output:

```
bruno@bigb:~/Work$ python playground/whereami.py 
cwd : /home/bruno/Work
__file__ : playground/whereami.py
abs file : /home/bruno/Work/playground/whereami.py
parent directory: /home/bruno/Work/playground
sibling with absolute path: /home/bruno/Work/playground/somefile.ext
```

As a side note:

First, **always** close your files - ok the current CPython implementation will close them when your program exits, but that's an implementation detail and not a part of the spec. The simplest way to make sure your files are closed is the `with` statement:

```
with open("somefile.ext") as input, open("otherfile.ext", "w") as output:
   # do something with output and input here
   # ...
```

# at this point (out of the `with` block),
   # both files will be closed.

Second point, `file.readlines()` will read the whole file in memory. If you only want ot iterate once over the lines in your file, just iterate over the file itself, it will avoids eating memory:

```
 with open("somefile.ext") as f:
     for line in f:
         print f
```

Comment: are you calling the `main` function after your code. The reason i say this is I see your stackoverflow point is 1. I'm guessing you are new to programming in python. you need to add `main()` on the next line after your `main` body definition

Comment: is the whereami.py file supposed to be included in the file I'm trying to write

Comment: also how would I depend on the current working directory?

Comment: @user130306 no obviously, it's just an example illustrating how to build an absolute path from the script's path. wrt "how would I depend on the current working directory" : as I say, if you don't give an absolute path, your path _will_ be resolved against the current working directory - that's how it works, period..